# RecyclerView itemDecoration does not work for a CardView containing a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have a `RecyclerView` to which I am adding some `ItemDecorations` programatically. The view contains items that are of type `CardView` and have a `ConstraintLayout`, but the decoration does not seem to apply properly for this item layout. It works fine if I swap `CardView` and `ConstraintLayout` or if I use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `CardView`.

I added the item decoration like so:

```
RecyclerView.ItemDecoration leftPaddedDividerDecoration = 
new DividerItemDecoration(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dividerheight),
                                     ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider),
                                     resources.getDimensionPixelSize(leftPadding),
                                     0
searchResultsRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(leftPaddedDividerDecoration);
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{item::onItemClicked}"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >

                  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ad_item_spacing_1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bottomSideButton"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
       />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
        />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

All I am trying to do is add a left padding to the divider under each item of this vertical `RecyclerView`. Also why is the divider get affected by what views are inside the RV?

Comment: Curious why this does not apply properly.